# Is there any way to get the updated state inside a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component, react-state

Let's took a look a this functional component :

note : this is just an exemple

```
function Foo() {

 const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 
 const GetData = () => {
  //setting the data...
  setData([1, 2, 3]);
 }
 
 const ShowData = (data) => {
  if(data)
     console.log(data);
}

useEffect( () => {
  GetData();
  ShowData(data)
},[]);

console.log(data) // Here I get the new data normally;
return (
<>
 <h2>Hello world ! </h2>
</>
)}
```

So my question is how can I get the updated value ( the new value of data ) to use it inside ShowData function ?

Comment: `ShowData` will be redeclared on every render, but you're shadowing the outer state with the `data` parameter. The `ShowData(data)` call inside your `useEffect` won't show the updated value because it is called in the same render cycle as the data is being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use another useEffect with data as dependency, so everytime data is updated you will run showData() like the following

```
useEffect( () => {
  GetData(); 
},[]); 

useEffect( () => {
  ShowData()
},[data]); // runs when data is updated
```

this way you don't need to pass data argument to showData fn. You will get the state updated.

Comment: What if the the showData function is fired when clicking on button ? Putting it in useEffect make no sense

Comment: if you want to call showData from a click event. You dont need useEffect you just need onClick prop in button `<button onClick={showData} />` Data will be updated as you called GetData in the first render

Answer (score 0):

On first render use

```
useEffect(() => {
  GetData();
},[]);
```

Then we also add a useEffect with data in the dependency array - which means it will run the code every time data changes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  ShowData(data)
},[data]);
```

Since data will be empty on first render you could do something like this in getData to just skip the function if data is not available yet.

```
const ShowData = (data) => {
   if(!data) return; //if there is no data yet, dont read code below
   
   console.log(data);
}
```

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1mtp5Lxs/3/)

Comment: What if the the showData function is fired when clicking on button ? Putting it in useEffect make no sense ?